# How to call dpois_raw C stats routine from R

Tags: c, r, external

I'm trying to figure out a way to call stats package's "dpois_raw" routine rather than the "dpois" wrapper using .Call .External or whatever means.

"dpois_raw" is not listed in the package environment `(stats:::C_*)` nor when I do `getDLLRegisteredRoutines("stats")` so I am probably out of luck, but I wonder whether someone R/C expert knows of a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dpois_raw` routine is provided by the `Rmath.h` header, and it doesn't appear to actually be exposed as part of the `stats` package (or otherwise); however, it is made available to C / C++ code through the `Rmath.h` header.

The simplest way to expose it would be with your own C / C++ code exposing that code, e.g. (code stub)

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rmath.h>

SEXP my_dpois_raw(<...>) {
   double result = dpois_raw(<...>);
   return result;
}
```

This routine would then be callable from R with something like

```
.Call("my_dpois_raw", <...>)
```

See Hadley's [r-pkgs](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html) section on using compiled code in R packages for some more information on including C / C++ code in an R package.

Comment: Yup, seems that hack the wrapper is the only way... I was hopping for a solution that would work out of the box but it seems that is rather impossible. Thank you.